Next JS tailwind css how to set larger and fix input size
i would like to create a large input field for my homepage, just like the Google Search displaying a large search bar centered in page
Here is my code
<div className="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
<div className="p-10">
  <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">input size get longer if i put a longer sentence here.</h1>
  <Autocomplete />
</div>
</div>

Results:



I want a wider input field, and increase the height of input field. Also fix its size so it doesnt change with the h2 above it . How can i do that please ?

what styles do you apply on your input?

i'm using shadcn/ui input component

have tried adding paddings or changing input height with tailwind classes?

It looks like the <Autocomplete /> here is a custom component, can you share what it is? The code given now doesn't reproduce the style in your screenshot.

How about this? I didn't change any styles of the shadcn/ui components
